# SQL Server Polybase Data Movement Service stopping after few seconds

Tags: sql-server, polybase

I have been scratching my head for a while now on how to fix this issue, SQL Server Polybase Data Movement Service starts successfully however after a few seconds it just stops. The OS on our server went corrupt last week and force us to reload the OS(Windows Server 2016 Data Center), which meant I had to reinstall and reconfigure Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Enterprise. Since this I cannot get the data movement engine to start and stay running as I have a few process that relies on this I am really in need of some advice.

I have found an Microsoft article below which if I look at error:3409 (Which I cannot seem to find in the logs) is referring to registry access. I have always installed and configured Microsoft Sql Server to only use the service accounts for the Engine and the Agent and leave the other services to the defaults.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15

See logs

**MSSQLSERVER_DET1_Dms_movement**

*2020/04/03 3:14:28 PM [Thread:114900] [CommandManager:ErrorEvent] (Error, High): 
Shared memory segment has not been created or attached.
Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.SharedMemory.NativeSharedMemoryException: Shared memory segment has not been created or attached.
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.SharedMemory.NativeSharedMemory.ThrowIfInvalid()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.SharedMemory.NativeSharedMemory.SetDistributionCount(Int32 distrCount)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.Nodes.DMSChannelMap.UpdateSharedMemoryDistributionCount()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.Nodes.DMSChannelMap.AddDataChannelReceiver(String nodeName, DataChannelReceiver dataChannelReceiver)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.CommandManager.StartDataChannel(Int32 senderQueueSize, Int32 tcpBufferSize, HashSet`1 nodesToConnect)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.CommandManager.ProcessStartDataChannel(IMessage message)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.DataWarehouse.DataMovement.CommandManager.ProcessBaseMessage(IBaseMessage message)
2020/04/03 3:14:28 PM [Thread:114900] [CommandManager:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Shutting down.
2020/04/03 3:14:28 PM [Thread:12864] [DataChannelReceiver:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): DataChannelReceiver DataChannelReceiver.Run--DET1:1433: Localhost DET1:1433 connected to RemoteHost DET1:1433: Initiating Run loop.
2020/04/03 3:14:28 PM [Thread:114900] [GeneralInstrumentation:SynchronousLogEvent] (Info, Normal): DMS Exit() called: Forceful shutdown initiated...
2020/04/03 3:14:28 PM [Thread:93816] [DMSDataChannelSenderClient:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): DMSDataChannelClient created
2020/04/03 3:14:28 PM [Thread:93816] [DataChannelSender:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Starting CreditFeedbackReceiver thread: CreditFeedbackReceiver.Run--DET1
2020/04/03 3:14:28 PM [Thread:93816] [CommandManager:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Started data channel, node: DET1, type: Sender
2020/04/03 3:14:28 PM [Thread:84568] [CommandManager:InformationEvent] (Info, Normal): Started data channel, node: DET1, type: CreditFeedback*

**UPDATE**
When stopping the SQL Sever Polybase Engine and then Trying to start the Polybase Data Movement Service, then the service remain started until I start the Polybase Engine Service then back to square 1 again.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be a permissions issue with the DWConfiguration/ DWDiagnostics and DWQueue databases that I just reattached after the reinstall of the OS, for some reason the [NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE] user did not have the correct permissions on these databases and thus the service kept on failing.

I managed to debug this with an extended events session trying to capture all queries that would touch these databases.

Thank you for all the help and support

Answer (score 0):

I should recommend doing a clean SQL Server install or repair. Just be aware that if you have a SQL Server installation on a server and you make it join a domain, please be aware that permissions issues will raise. So join a domain first before instaling SQL Server since you won't be able to change Domain name to controler and a Domain controller to domain name.

Comment: Hi this site does not run like a forum.  And you r post does not sound like an answer.  It may get deleted.

Comment: will update my anwser. thx

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered same issue as described above but non of recommended solutions work.
in my case Polybase service account has correct permissions, but for security reasons we disabled "Named pipe" endpoint in our SQL Server instance and after i start this endpoint again the issue was resolved completely.

```
ALTER ENDPOINT [TSQL Named Pipes] STATE=STARTED;
```